# Placing 5 people on chairs so that 2 people never sit together

Tags: combinatorics

We have a family composed by 2 parents and 3 children that have to seat on 5 chairs (in line), two of the children don't want to stay together, how many are the ways that they can sit?

I was thinking about letting one of the 2 children sit first, now the second one can sit only on 3 chairs, the remaining parents and child now can sit on the other 3 chairs

So I came to that expression: 3*3! = 18 but I saw that this wasn't the correct answer...

Comment: Are the chairs in a circle or in a line?  If it's a circle, there are only $2$ paces the second child can sit.  If it's a line, the calculation is more complicated, because it depends on whether the first child sits at the end of the row or not.

Comment: they are in a line

Comment: Use the hint you were given in the first comment. In any case you heavily undercount even in your model.

Comment: Further hint: There are 2 methods (at least). 1) Find the total number of arrangements of the 5 people ($=5!$) and from this subtract the number of arrangements where the 2 fussy children are next to each other (they can be treated as 1 item except that they can sit 2 possible ways round.) 2) Find the number of ways of arranging the other 3 ($=3!$) and multiply this by the number of ways of inserting the 2 fussy children into the arrangement.

Comment: As @saulspatz has just given a compete answer by a third method, let me just say that 1) gives $5!-2.4!=72$ and 2) gives $3!.2.6=72$

Comment: Per the comment of @MichaelCohen, I favor the approach of $(5!)$ minus the *dis-satisfying* seating arrangements.  For dis-satisfaction enumeration, pretend that Fussy-1, Fussy-2 are *joined at the hip* into 1 **unit**.  Then, to enumerate the dis-satisfaction, you are permuting $(4)$ *units*.  Also, within each *unit*, Fussy-1, Fussy-2 can be permuted in $(2!)$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

If the chairs are in a line, then the calculation must take into account  where the first child sits.  There are two ways for him to take a seat on the end, then three ways for the other child to take a seat.  There are three ways for the first child to take a seat in the middle of the row, and then there are only two ways for the second child to take a seat.  So there are in all $$2\cdot3+3\cdot2=12$$ ways for the two of them to be seated.  There are then $3!$ ways to seat the rest of the family, so $72$ ways in all.

Answer (score -1):

I think your idea is correct, you just miss some calculation.
I will assume here that the 5 chair are put in circle

So yes, let first choose the chair of one of the difficult child (5 choices, 4 chairs left)

Then the second difficult choose from the 2 chairs which are not together (1 chair as 2 neighbour, and one chair is already taken) (so 2 choices, and 3 chair left)

At least let the 3 other sit (3! choices)

So tu sums up, we have $5\times2\times 3! =60$ possibilities

Is this your expected answer, or did i miss something in the initial statement ?

Comment: the chairs are in line

Comment: The answer is not 60.

Comment: You missed that in the event the first problem child sat at an end chair they are not considered as "neighboring" the other end chair.  In such a scenario, there are in fact *three* choices, not just two, for where the other problem child can sit.